# EF Core can't detect existing database and creates new one on context.Database.Migrate() PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, migration, npgsql

I am using EF Core 6 with NPGSQL. Database is hosted on Azure and I am connecting to it using pgAdmin 4 successfully. My code is set up to call EF cores Migrate() on startup and as far as I know this method should create new db if the db with given name does not exist in the list. The issue is that before running the app I have checked in pgAdmin, the database exists, but ef core creates new one with exactly the same name.

I have checked database host url, username, password, database name. Everything is correct.

Comment: Check schema name and case of database name.

Comment: double checked, everything is correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.